# Connect Windows-based application to web based database SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to connect a Windows-based C# .net application to a WEB based SQL Server 2005?

Comment: What do you mean by "web-based SQL Server" ??? SQL Server is a full fledged server product - it's not really a web app per se....

Comment: thanx marc 
I established connection to my web based database server.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can see the SQL Server by either IP Address or name (possibly using NATing), you should be able to use the database on that server.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation

Comment: we can also connect to database using domain name of server.